# Web app to search and download high quality music from YouTube

Tags: youtube

I'm looking for a web app that lets you do the following:

1. User types in the name and artist of a song.
2. The search component: app goes to YouTube and fetches the video of that song with the highest quality audio. (Most likely this will be an unofficial lyrics video or picture video someone uploaded as a tribute to the original artist. Sometimes, the official music video.)
3. The download component: app strips the audio from the video, converts the audio to a format selected by the user, such as mp3, ideally applies correct tags to the audio file, and provides a link for the user to click to download the audio file.

Does such a web app or service exist?

Comment: sure - https://video.genyt.com/VP623hMbAIA

Comment: @user0 - that looks like the answer, then. It has M4A which should satisfy most requirements. You can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- go to **https://www.youtube.com/**
- search for the video you need
- add **`gen`** before **`youtube`** so the URL will look like:

  ```
  https://www.genyoutube.com/watch?v=TMVt7_7Uni8
  ```
- hit the **<kbd>`ENTER`</kbd>** key
- select what you want to download:

[image]